# In Python 3, how can we extract all span text entries ending in "<span>days ago<\span>"?

Tags: python, html, python-3.x

Currently, I am trying to use python 3 to grep text within an html file. I would like to take out elements like:

```
<span>11 days ago</span>
```

and

```
<a class="aksfjlasie22" data-click-id="timestamp" href="https://www.website.com" id="P" style="color:#787C7E" target="_blank" rel="nofollow noopener">11 days ago</a>
```

and instead just obtain `11 days ago` and `11` and put them into a list. There are many such entries and I would like to get them all. Is there a simple grep approach in Python 3?

Comment: The code snippet where the `11 days ago` text is present is under `<a>` tag. If yes, then you might have to search for both `<a>` and `<span>` tag using beautifulsoup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `BeautifulSoup` to get the work done.

```
from  bs4 import BeautifulSoup

text = """
<span>11 days ago</span>
<a class="aksfjlasie22" data-click-id="timestamp" href="https://www.website.com" id="P" style="color:#787C7E" target="_blank" rel="nofollow noopener">12 days ago</a>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(text, "html.parser")

print([span.text for span in soup.find_all(["a", "span"])])

['11 days ago', '12 days ago']
```

Comment: The question seems to look for both `<a>` and `<span>` tag text, it would be better to update the answer containing both the tags to perform a find.

Comment: the answer is still looking for both tags separately, you can combine the HTML containing both `<a>` and `<span>` tag in one example like the other answer however using bs4.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this regex:

```
<\s*(?:span|a)[^>]*>(.*?)<\s*/\s*(?:span|a)>
```

use as so:

```py
import re

text = """
<span>20 days ago</span>
<a class="aksfjlasie22" data-click-id="timestamp" href="https://www.website.com" id="P" style="color:#787C7E" target="_blank" rel="nofollow noopener">11 days ago</a>
"""

matches = re.findall(r"<\s*(?:span|a)[^>]*>(.*?)<\s*/\s*(?:span|a)>", text)

# ['20 days ago', '11 days ago']
```

Note that this is not a good way to parse HTML. For more robust usage try [html.parser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.parser.html) or [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) (as noted in the other answer), depending on how complex